# Constant infinite loops when trying to pass data from child to parent component on the mount BUT after ive set some state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ill put the code from the Parent and Child component, then explain my issue.
Parent:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import close from "./static/close.svg";

import ValidatorInput from "./components/ValidatorInput";

const blueTheme = {
  lightColour: "#A8DCF3",
  darkestColour: "#417397",
};

const formTitle = "Signup";

function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [globalValidatorsCount, setGlobalValidatorsCount] = useState(0);

  function submitHandler(e) {
    console.log(globalValidatorsCount);
    e.preventDefault();
    openModal();
  }

  async function openModal() {
    await setTimeout(function () {
      setShowModal(true);
    }, 500);
  }

  function closeModal() {
    setShowModal(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="body">
      <div style={showModal ? { background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)", height: "100vh", width: "100%", position: "absolute", zIndex: "500" } : {}}></div>
      <div className="modal" style={showModal ? { display: "flex" } : { display: "none" }}>
        <p className="modalText" style={{ color: blueTheme.darkestColour }}>
          You have clicked the button. Add confirm of form validity at some point for improvement.
        </p>
        <img src={close} alt="close" onClick={closeModal} className="modalClose" />
      </div>
      <section
        className="cardContainer"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: `white`,
          border: `1px solid ${blueTheme.darkColour}`,
        }}
      >
        <h1 style={{ color: `${blueTheme.darkestColour}` }}>{formTitle}</h1>
        <form>
          <ValidatorInput
            lightColour={blueTheme.lightColour}
            darkestColour={blueTheme.darkestColour}
            label="Username"
            validators={["MinLength"]}
            callbackParent={setGlobalValidatorsCount}
          />
          <ValidatorInput
            lightColour={blueTheme.lightColour}
            darkestColour={blueTheme.darkestColour}
            label="Email"
            validators={["Email"]}
            callbackParent={setGlobalValidatorsCount}
          />
          <ValidatorInput
            lightColour={blueTheme.lightColour}
            darkestColour={blueTheme.darkestColour}
            label="Password"
            validators={["MinLength", "Capital"]}
            callbackParent={setGlobalValidatorsCount}
          />
        </form>
        <button
          type="submit"
          style={{ borderColor: `${blueTheme.darkestColour}`, backgroundColor: `${blueTheme.lightColour}` }}
          onClick={submitHandler}
          className="ripple"
        >
          <span className="buttonText" style={{ color: `${blueTheme.darkestColour}` }}>
            Signup
          </span>
        </button>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./ValidatorInput.css";
import passwordHidden from "../static/passwordHidden.svg";
import passwordShown from "../static/passwordShown.svg";

import MinLength from "../validators/MinLength";
import Capital from "../validators/Capital";
import Email from "../validators/Email";

export default function ValidatorInput(props) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(null);
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [validatorsCount, setValidatorsCount] = useState(0);

  const { validators } = props;

  function inputChangeHandler(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  }

  function passwordToggleHandler(e) {
    showPassword === false ? setShowPassword(true) : setShowPassword(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (validators.includes("MinLength")) {
      setValidatorsCount((v) => v + 1);
    }
    if (validators.includes("Capital")) {
      setValidatorsCount((v) => v + 1);
    }
    if (validators.includes("Email")) {
      setValidatorsCount((v) => v + 1);
    }
  }, [validators]);

  function callbackToParent(valCount) {
    props.callbackParent((v) => v + valCount);
  }

    // callbackToParent(validatorsCount);
    console.log(validatorsCount);
  }, [validatorsCount]);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <p className="label" style={{ color: `${props.darkestColour}` }}>
        {props.label}
      </p>
      <input
        type={props.label.toLowerCase() === "password" ? `${!showPassword && "password"}` : "text"}
        className={props.label.toLowerCase() === "password" ? "input passwordPadding" : "input"}
        style={{
          borderColor: `${props.darkestColour}`,
          backgroundColor: `${props.lightColour}`,
        }}
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
      />
      {/* password hidden */}
      {props.label.toLowerCase() === "password" && showPassword === false && (
        <img src={passwordHidden} alt="passwordToggle" className="passwordToggle" onClick={passwordToggleHandler} />
      )}
      {/* password shown */}
      {props.label.toLowerCase() === "password" && showPassword === true && (
        <img src={passwordShown} alt="passwordToggle" className="passwordToggle" onClick={passwordToggleHandler} />
      )}

      {/* Validators */}
      {props.validators.includes("MinLength") && <MinLength inputValue={inputValue} minLength={6} />}

      {props.validators.includes("Capital") && <Capital inputValue={inputValue} />}

      {props.validators.includes("Email") && <Email inputValue={inputValue} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The parent is a card containing a title and a form. I have 3 "validatorInput" components(the children). Each one includes a label, the input field, and a validators prop which you can pass in depending which validators  you want.
The issue here is , i need to grab how many validators there are in every child component and pass it to the parent to compare with the amount that are passed validations to see if overall form is valid.
Im already setting the individual validators per component and have stored them successfully ( the useEffect in child does this ) But i need to pass this data to the parent AFTER the state has been set in each child component(so i can set the globalValidatorsCount state). I have a callback function already setup in the parent however each time i try to go into infinite loops or it just doesnt work.

Comment: is validators an array or a string? either way I think that's the issue which is causing infinite rerendering

Comment: @EugenSunic its an array of strings, i check which ones each child component recives in its props. It never changes unless you manually change it in each component

Comment: now you know what causes the loop, you are always referring to the reference which never changes

Comment: @EugenSunic Notice in each <validatorInput> i have a validators prop. For the example code above ^^ there is 4 OVERALL validators provided. I want to store how many are provided in state in the main parent ( app.js ) component. But as they are props and can change i have to extract from the child and pass it back up to the parent